# Post request with checkbox and select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I have a html table with rows that gets created inside a forloop with first element checkbox having unique value and same name ("checkboxes") and last element, a select element with same name ("selects") and same options. I am trying to send the selected checkbox and the associated option to a post request. Because when I am doing

```
d=parse_qs(request_body)
selected_opt=d.get('selects',[''])
```

selected_opt returns all the value even if I have not selected the checkbox. Since I have to create a dictionary of checkbox value(key) and corresponding selected option (value).

Comment: can you share a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: you need to use a diagram or sample code to help us get the picture

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666811/post-data-with-select-option

Comment: okay so check my answer it will help u.

Answer (score 0):

Just from what I tried to understand try something like this(only for getting the data write the rest by your self.):

```
data = []

$("input[type='checkbox'] :checked").each(function(){
            parentRow = $(this).parent()

            //key=>checkbox val, val => select input val
            data.push({$(this).val() : parentRow.find("select").val()})
        });

    //use data variable as ur ajax data
    sendAjax(data)
```

Comment: <script>
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
  data=[]
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    parentRow=$(this).parent()
    data.push({$(this).val() : parentRow.find("select").val()})
    });
  var sendAjax=$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"http://localhost:8050/check_myws_params",
      data:data
    });
</script>
error on line data.push on javascript console(unexpected '(' ). also it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: what is this, if my answer helped you dont forget accepting it.

Comment: and how do I get the request variables in check_myws_params function?

Comment: if u are in php change your checkbox input name from `checkboxes` to `checkboxes[]` then on your backend u can access it as an array `$_POST['checkboxes'][i]`